# BASH read a line but evaluate just a part

Tags: bash

I try to read a file line by line, and write each line after evaluating them in a new file.

Code is like that :

```
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ "<"*">" ]]
    then
      echo $line > bew_file.txt
    fi
    eval echo $line > test.txt
done < file.txt
```

In the file.txt it's a typically apache conf file.

```
Alias /access "$VID"/
<Directory "$VIDEOREP">
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
</Directory>
```

If a do an `eval echo` on line with `<*>` i have an error like :

> Directory: No such file or directory

So i put this condition : `if [[ $line =~ "<"*">" ]]`  to not eval line with `<*>` but now `$VIDEOREP` for example cannot have value..

How can i read line with `<*>` and evaluate value inside the line ?

**EDIT : i cannot touch the file.txt**

Comment: It is not clear why are you doing `eval`?

Comment: You need to quote all variables with `"$var"`

Comment: take the line `<Directory "$VIDEOREP">` in the new bew_file.txt this line is `<Directory /home/directory>`

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words and remove `eval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properly quoting your variables also removes the need to special-case `<*>` strings, which was an incomplete security measure anyway; there are many other strings which could trip various errors when you use them unquoted.

```
while read -r line; do
    eval echo "'$line'"
done <file.txt >bew_file.txt
```

(I assume you want all the output to the same file, not two different files where each contains only the last line of the generated output.)

However, this still has numerous other issues.  My recommendation would be to replace only the variables you actually know you want to replace and get rid of the `eval`.

```
sed "s%\$VIDEOREP%$VIDEOREP%g;s%\$VID%$VID%g" file.txt >bew_file.txt
```

Comment: nice one ! the `sed` is a brilliant idea

Answer (score 1):

A funny possibility is to use this:

```
#!/bin/bash

VID="vid_replacement"
VIDEOREP="video_replacement"

. <(cat <<EOF
cat <<EOF2
$(< file.txt)
EOF2
EOF
)
```

The only constraint is that you can't have the line

```
EOF2
```

in `file.txt`, but that's very unlikely. Of course, arbitrary code execution is possible, e.g., if your file contains `$(ls)`, but that can be a feature… just make sure that you were the one who generated the file `file.txt`; don't run this if the file comes from untrusted/malicious user.

---

What happens?

The `cat` in the process substitution:

```
cat <<EOF
cat <<EOF2
$(< file.txt)
EOF2
EOF
```

will output to stdint the following:

```
cat <<EOF2
Alias /access "$VID"/
<Directory "$VIDEOREP">
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </IfVersion>
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
</Directory>
EOF2
```

Then this is *sourced* (thanks to the `. <( ... )` term), and in this case the content of the here-doc is subject to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion: exactly what you want.

Comment: I see what you did there, but perhaps it should be spelled out.

Comment: @tripleee is that ok?

Comment: Yeah, upvoted for cleverness, with some hesitation.  It's got pretty much the same problems as the `eval` it is supposed to replace, and possibly some new ones.

Comment: @tripleee: it has got problems but not as bad as the `eval`: the `<` and `>` and `&`, etc. are not badly interpreted. The file is only subject to parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion, i.e., the only problem will be the `$` and `\`` symbols. This might actually be a feature for dynamic generation. I'm assuming that the file is never going to be edited by a an unauthorized user (hey, it's an apache config file, so this assumption is likely fulfilled)—and I actually explicitly wrote a warning/caveat about it.